# how to make building environment for AGL?

Tags: automotive, iot-for-automotive, automotive-grade-linux, android-automotive

I want to implement or create a bhuild environment for Automotive Grade Linux that I can virtually create some which is to be installed on AGL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker container setup for AGL SDK.
[Refer this link](http://docs.automotivelinux.org/master/docs/getting_started/en/dev/reference/setup-sdk-environment.html)

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Use instead a comment, or edit your question so as it answers the question *even without the link*.